# pivotal cloud foundry spring boot embedded tomcat

Tags: tomcat, cloud, spring-boot

I am deploying  my spring boot 1.2.2 app with tomcat as provided dependency in pcf.

The java build pack I'm using provides tomcat.

Looks like my app always uses the  bundled tomcat instead of the provided tomcat (from buildpack).

How do i resolve this ?

Comment: How you are finding this? That you app is using bundled tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

You can include a manifest.yml file in your application directory and specify this env variable in the manifest.yml file.

```
env:
    JBP_CONFIG_TOMCAT: '{tomcat: { version: 8.0.+ }}'
```

This is a link to sample [manifest.yml](https://github.com/scottfrederick/spring-music/blob/master/manifest.yml) file that you can use as a sample format.

Include this env variable within your manifest.yml file and specify the version number that you want to use.